# Only allow user to select one Checkbutton at a time?

Tags: python, tkinter

Is there a way to only allow a user to check one `Checkbutton` widget at a time out of a set of `Checkbutton` widgets? I can imagine some brute-force solutions, but I'm looking for something elegant.

Answer (score 6):

You can tie all the checkbutton to single variable with different *onvalue*.

```
import tkinter

root = tk.Tk()            #Creating the root window
var = tk.IntVar()         #Creating a variable which will track the selected checkbutton
cb = []                   #Empty list which is going to hold all the checkbutton
for i in range(5):
    cb.append(tk.Checkbutton(root, onvalue = i, variable = var))  
                          #Creating and adding checkbutton to list
    cb[i].pack()          #packing the checkbutton

root.mainloop()           #running the main loop
```

I have created them in a loop for demonstration purpose. Even when you create them sequentially you can use the same variable name with different onvalue.